# Get the current posts's taxonomies terms to display them as an id

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have the following code, and basically want it to display the term's slug in the data-type="HERE" part. This is on a static html page outside of the wordpress installation.

I have it displaying the custom post types as a list, but can't get it to display the terms from the taxonomy of 'categories'.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'case_study' ); ?>
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/news/wp-load.php'); query_posts($args );  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li data-id="id-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-type="DISPLAY TAXONOMY OF CATERGORIES TERMS HERE">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('case-study-thumb'); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <li>No Case Studies found</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered an answer on the forum, works a charm!

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'categories' ); foreach( $terms as $term ) {  print $term->slug;  unset($term); }?>
```

Where 'print $term->slug;' is, the slug can be changed to name to print the name of the taxonomy term :-)

Comment: Hello, and how to link to taxonomy page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category), for example :

```
$data_type = '';
$categories= get_the_category();
if (is_array($categories)) foreach($categories as $cat) {
  $data_type .= ', '.$cat->cat_name;
}
```